# How to use one Action Listener for buttons that require different method parameters?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to reduce the amount of button action listeners I have by simply calling one Action Listener:

```
ActionListener calculatorListener = new ActionListener(){
             @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int x = 9;
                calc.calculate(x);
            }
        };

JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
        buttonPanel.add(button9);

        button9.addActionListener(calculatorListener);

JButton button8 = new JButton("8");

buttonPanel.add(button8);

 button8.addActionListener(calculatorListener); //etc.....
```

I have many different buttons, but need the parameter in the one ActionListener (x for example) to be different for each button that uses the ActionListener. Is there a way that the action listener can detect which JButton is being used?

Comment: try with e.getSource()

Comment: but why, if they are doing different things, do you want it in the same actionListener? that 'll just make that code harder to read and add more complexity (you're adding conditions you don't need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways of accomplishing your goal.  Here's one that's fairly simple and straightforward.

First, make your action listener a named class that you can construct with a parameter:

```
private class CalcListener implements ActionListener {
    private int x;
    private CalcListener(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        calc.calculate(x);
    }
}
```

Then, use it like this:

```
button1.addActionListener(new CalcAction(1));
...
button8.addActionListener(new CalcAction(8));
button9.addActionListener(new CalcAction(9));
```

Comment: And you can have `CalcAction` extend `AbstractAction` (and implement appropriate constructors), so the `CalcAction` carries its own name and icon if you like, and can pass that to `JButton` or `JMenuItem` creation, like `new JButton(new CalcAction("8", 8))`, giving you a `JButton` labelled with the action's name "8" and invoking the `actionPerformed()` with the extra parameter. And you can use the same `Action` in multiple places.